# SQL Server engine in one place with database files on NAS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, migration, configuration, storage

My office uses accountant programs which run on SQL Server 2008 R2. The SQL Server engine must be installed on one of the laptops (called "server") and the other laptops (called "clients") connect to it via local network. Database files are stored in the same place as the SQL Server engine, so on the "server" laptop. From the security point of view, this is the most ridiculous solution anyone could have so I'm trying to change that.

Is it possible to MOVE only the database files (.mdf) to the NAS which we own, so the SQL Server engine will still run on the "server" laptop but the database will be stored on secured NAS in other place?

Unfortunately it's impossible to install SQL Server on the NAS because it's Synology so it doesn't have MS compatibility (it does have MySQL though).

Comment: It should be possible, if your NAS system supports the SMB protocol (e.g. Samba). Don't get too exited about performance though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I wouldn't want my database on a NAS as it is most likely accessed throughout the office and it is also very vulnerable as everyone connects to it. Ideally, your SQL database should be hidden in the deepest parts of your network.

However, I seeing how this doesn't sound like a high end operation, I would see if they can give you the money to get a desktop and install SQL express there to run the database for them. That way all of your clients can just connect to that server from within the network and you have a central point to pull backups from.

Comment: This NAS actually is not accessible by other members of the office. It does share two folders with the employees but they have their own logins - otherwise they won't be able to access it.

I have some old PC with quite enough power to be a SQL server (it used to be a movie making machine) but that's not the point, my friend. I bought the Synology with 16TB in Raid1 so I could use it not only as a backup, but also as a server. Pity I didn't check that before buying :)

Comment: As far as I understand, I should now install the "Server" version of the accountant program on the PC machine in other facility, set a static IP of that machine and just

Answer (score 0):

SQL doesn't support database files on SMB prior to 2012. Otherwise it would be possible but not recommended.

Your priority should be regular backups of system and user databases, which can be done to an SMB share (best way to do it actually!)

Comment: Oh, that's bad news Cody. Still, thank You for the proposed solution, but unfortunately it's not about the backups. It's about that laptops in the company could be this software's clients so actually they wouldn't store any company client's sensitive informations on the hard drives.

The problem with building a SQL server in other place is that our other facility don't have good internet connection - the max is 2mbit/s I think. So may be that downloading would be fine, but uploading... it would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the scenario you describe.

I have one server upon which SQL SERVER 2008 R2 is installed and some of the databases are also stored on it. I have one database which the mdf file is on a NAS drive. The NAS drive has dropbox installed so the mdf file is constantly being backed up. with a 1Gbit network performance is very good.

The NAS drive has been added to my domain so normal AD permissions are applied to the directories thereon.

The only thing to remember is that if you update the firmware on the NAS drive, you need to suspend SQL Server whilst you do it or it may corrupt the database. SQL Server would then put the database in recovery and it will *eventually* be available again. Remembering to pause the SQL Server will save you a lot of waiting time (learned from experience!)